# Sylow $p$-sugroup is normal in a group of order $4p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $p$ is prime and $p\geq 5$. Show that the Sylow $p$-subgroup is normal in a group of order $4p$. Is it true for $p=3$?

Comment: Hint: if there is only one subgroup of a certain order, then that is normal.

Comment: Why are there so many downvotes here?

Comment: @JorgeFernández: This is a PSQ.

Answer (score 4):

When $p$ is at least $5$ you just have to use the the number of sylow p-subgroups is a divisor of $4$ congruent to $1$ $\bmod p$.

When $p$ is $3$ consider the alternating group.

Comment: Hint: the alternating subgroup has $4$ subgroups of order $3$.